# State is not updating when initalizing it with server side props and navigating with next/link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

Below is my Minimal Reproducible Example of my problem. I am calling the `getServerSideProps` to get some values from the Database, this value is set as the state in the Component. This is because the value need to be changed so that I can send it back to Database via an API.

The URL path variable is read in the `getServerSideProps` so that the appropriate data can be fetched from the DB.

The form work perfectly if I load the page from the address bar or change the URL in the address bar or refresh the page.

But when I am using the `next/link` to navigate to the next page, the old state doesn't get refreshed with the new prop.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this an anti-pattern?

MRE:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home(prop: any) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(prop.data.name);
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    //Send the name state to API.
    //await fakeAPI(name)
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>MRE</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />{" "}
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Send to API</button>
      <div>
        <Link href={`/${prop.index - 1}`}>Back</Link>&nbsp;
        <Link href={`/${prop.index + 1}`}>Next</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  const TEST_DB_DATA = [
    {
      name: "Test 0",
    },
    {
      name: "Test 1",
    },
    {
      name: "Test 2",
    },
  ];
  const index = parseInt(context.params?.data ?? "");
  return {
    props: {
      index,
      data: TEST_DB_DATA[index],
    },
  };
}
```

Gif of the Issue:

[image: Gif of the Issue]

Comment: Your whole component needs to be mapped into a Route in order for it to be aware that a page change has happened.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes

Comment: @TKoL I am not using react-router, I am using nextjs' page routes.

Comment: In that case you might need to use `useRouter` or `withRouter` to programmatically do different things when a page change happens - the simplest case here would be to have your HOME component appearing inside another component, with a `key` that updates depending on the route. If you update the key in `<Home key={}`, it will treat it like a fresh component

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, not sure if this is a right method. But I have added an event to detect the page load, then used that event to set the state, now the state is changing when the 'next/link' is used.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
...


export default function Home(prop: any) {

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => {
      setName(prop.data.name);
    });
  }, [router]);


return ...
...
}
```